# RxJs: repeatedly check the value of a global variable until the value meet requirement or reach maximum timelimit

Tags: timer, rxjs

In my Angular application, I have a usage case where I need to check the property value on the `window` global object (This property value is set by other async operations). And based on the value, I need to update something on the UI, that's background for this post.

I figure out one solution, partial meet my target, but need a little tuning. The code is as following:

```
import { of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, map, pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = timer(1000, 1000)

const example = source.pipe(
  map((v) => {
    return {
      currentTime: v,
      currentStatus: Boolean((window as any).Test)
    }
  }),
  takeWhile(val => {
    return !val.currentStatus && val.currentTime <= 10
  }),
  pluck('currentStatus')
);

const subscribe = example.subscribe(
  val => console.log(val),
  () => console.log("error"),
  () => console.log("complete")
);

setTimeout(() => {
  (window as any).Test = "Test"
}, 4500)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sg1n41?file=index.ts

I use `timer` to repeatedly do the task and use `takeWhile` to stop the timer when the conditions are matched. There are two conditions to stop the timer: 1) the value becomes from undefined to what I need 2) or the maximum timelimit is reached.

For testing purpose, I manually set the value with `setTimeout()`.

The current result of the final observable is:  `false, false, false, false`. But in fact, I need the final `true` value. `takeWhile` doesn't take the final value.

Is there any method to tune it to what I need?

Comment: Are you tied to RxJS 6.2.2 (from your StackBlitz setup)? If not and you can use 6.4+, `takeWhile` has an optional second argument, which when set to `true`, will also emit the final value. [Here's a fork with it in action.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-icqwhq?file=index.ts)

Comment: oh, great to know. It seems that this is a new feature. I will try. You comment should the answer of this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [RxJS v6.4+](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-640-2019-01-30), `takeWhile` accepts a second argument which controls whether or not to emit the value which causes it to complete.

The required usage is simply setting that second argument to `true`:

```
   takeWhile(..., true)
```

[And here's a demonstration of that in use.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-icqwhq?file=index.ts)